# Asp.Net MVC RedirectAction or Shared method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post-redirect-get

In an action of my controller, I must execute another action of the same controller. Both actions are in the same security context. Should I have to call a RedirectAction to execute the other action or should I have to create a shared method that both actions can called?

**As example for using RedirectAction:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Search(string value)
{
   IPresenter presenter = new Presenter();
   List<Item> items = presenter.GetList(value);

   if (items.Count > 1)
      return base.View("List", items);
   else
      return base.RedirectAction("Detail", new { id = items.First().Id });
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{
   IPresenter presenter = new Presenter();

   return base.View(presenter.GetItemById(id));
}
```

**And an example using shared method:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Search(string value)
{
   IPresenter presenter = new Presenter();
   List<Item> items = presenter.GetList(value);

   if (items.Count > 1)
      return base.View("List", items);
   else
      return this.GetDetail(id);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{
   return this.GetDetail(id);
}

private ActionResult GetDetail(int id)
{
    IPresenter presenter = new Presenter();

    return base.View(presenter.GetItemById(id));
}
```

In the Shared method case, I have one http request less than in the RedirectAction case but with the RedirectAction, I have a flow that is more natural with Asp.Net MVC ways.

Which case do you think is the best and why? And if both are good depending the situation, what are the good and the bad situations?

*Notes:
I intentionally don't use post query because I know that in this case, the [PRG Pattern](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201104/Blog/ASP-NET-MVC-Post-Redirect-Get-Pattern/) is essential to prevent unwanted behavior to the client where multiple posts could be send to the server while using the back button of the browser.*

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is good question.

Even if I'm not sure 100% about exactly right answer, I use 'Shared method' approach in my applications. The reason is - simplicity.

In the same time, you correctly noticed that `RedirectToAction` is more ASP.NET MVC way.

For a situation like you posted, I would avoid such behaviour at all. If user requested the 'List' of items, you should show him a list, even if there is only one item in collection. If he deciedes to check the details, he would click on it. Thus, you are having simple controller actions and clean views.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a, as you say, shared method. If you do `RedirectToAction` it results in a new request to your Webbserver.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm maybe u should just return another view in action. f.e.:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Search(string value)
{
    IPresenter presenter = new Presenter();
    List<Item> items = presenter.GetList(value);

    if (items.Count > 1)
    {
        return base.View("List", items);
    }  
    else
    {
        //your logic and model from Detail Action f.e:
        var model = repository.GetDetailModel(items.First().Id);

        return View("Detail", model);
    }
}
```